# Address book redirect to 'new' always when I click on address book

Tags: magento2, customer-account

In account pages when I click on address book on left side panel it redirect to add new address form  with url `customer/address/new/`

while , In actual I should go to index where I can see address in address book.

Why its happening any idea ?

Comment: It's magento default functionality @Learner which is used for create new address for customer

Comment: @RohanHapani  I saved address 4,5 times still it goes to new form , but suddenly on 6th attempt It went to address book. Is it because  address was not properly saved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirecting on New Address Form, When user don't have any address is default functionlity of magento. 
If you want to overwrite this, you need to create plugin and overwrite the default functionlity like below:

Specify new `plugin` class in `app/code/Stack/Customer/etc/di.xml` file using the below code:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Address\Index">
        <plugin name="address-index" type="Stack\Customer\Plugin\Controller\Address\Index" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>    
</config>
```

Create `plugin` file `app/code/Stack/Customer/Plugin/Controller/Address/Index.php` using the below code:

```
namespace Stack\Customer\Plugin\Controller\Address;
class Index
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect
    )
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_redirect = $redirect;
    }

    public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Address\Index $index, callable $proceed)
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('address_book');
        if ($block) {
            $block->setRefererUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        }
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Hope this help!!

Comment: what exactly it will do ? It will redirect always to address book ?

Comment: yes it will redirect on address index page always

Comment: thank you. let me try this :) and where I can change page ?where is its phtml file of Address book ? any idea ?

Comment: `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/address/book.phtml` -- you can copy this file in your theme in customer module